# Why is Flow created on ConflatedBroadcastChannel only able to receive last element?

Tags: kotlin, channel, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-coroutine-channel

The following code only prints 10000 i.e. only the last element

```kotlin
val channel = BroadcastChannel<Int>(Channel.CONFLATED)
val flowJob = channel.asFlow().buffer(Channel.UNLIMITED).onEach {
    println(it)
}.launchIn(GlobalScope)

for (i in 0..100) {
    channel.offer(i*i)
}
flowJob.join()
```

Code can be ran in the [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/LUFc07wq6).

But since the Flow is launched in separate dispatching thread, and value is sent to the Channel and since Flow has an unlimited buffer, it should receive each element till onEach is invoked. But why only the last element is able to get received?

Is this the expected behavior or some bug? If its expected behavior how would somebody try to push only the newest elements to the flow, but all the flow that has certain buffer can receive the element.

Comment: What is your use case for this? I'm not quite sure I understand the reason for conflating if missing elements is a problem for you

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is about the "Conflate" way of buffering. For buffering a flow you have a couple of ways such as using `buffer()` method or `collectLatest()` or `conflate()`. Each of them has their own way to buffer. So `conflate()` method's way is that when the flow emits values, it tries to collect but when the collector is too slow, then `conflate()` skips the intermediate values for the sake of the flow. And it's doing it even tho every time it's emitted in a separate coroutine. So in a channel, a similar thing is happening basically.

Here is the official doc explanation:

> When a flow represents partial results of the operation or operation
> status updates, it may not be necessary to process each value, but
> instead, only most recent ones. In this case, the conflate operator
> can be used to skip intermediate values when a collector is too slow
> to process them.

Check out this [link.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#conflation)

The explanation is for flow but you need to focus on the feature that you are using. And in this case, conflation is same for channel and flow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `Channel.CONFLATED`. Taken from the docs:

```
Channel that buffers at most one element and conflates all subsequent `send` and `offer` invocations,
so that the receiver always gets the most recently sent element.
Back-to-send sent elements are _conflated_ -- only the the most recently sent element is received,
while previously sent elements **are lost**.
Sender to this channel never suspends and [offer] always returns `true`.

This channel is created by `Channel(Channel.CONFLATED)` factory function invocation.

This implementation is fully lock-free.
```

so this is why you only get the most recent (last) element. I'd use an `UNLIMITED` `Channel` instead:

```kotlin
val channel = Channel<Int>(Channel.UNLIMITED)
val flowJob = channel.consumeAsFlow().onEach {
    println(it)
}.launchIn(GlobalScope)

for (i in 0..100) {
    channel.offer(i*i)
}
flowJob.join()
```

Comment: I think this is only part of the answer. Technically, if the `launchIn()` coroutine had started, even a conflated broadcast channel could send each element as they come to the flow, and the flow would print them. I think the problem is the combination of this conflated behaviour AND the fact that the coroutine is not started before hitting `join()`. Maybe a start `UNDISPATCHED` or a little `delay()` before the `for` loop would also solve the problem.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't wanted to create a heap storage of elements in the channel itself... Only the flow having buffer should store such elements, otherwise Channel should only send the recent elements to the non-buffered flow.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu the "problem" with using a conflated channel is that your `send()` calls never suspend (using `offer` is even worse), and therefore all your elements are sent by the `for` loop to the channel (and dropped due to conflation) before the flow's coroutine has any chance of receiving the elements. I even tested with a delay before the `for` loop, and it doesn't solve the problem. You would really need a suspension (like a delay) between each `send` to allow the flow to receive the elements. The fact that the flow has a buffer or not doesn't matter if it can't even receive anything.

Comment: Instead of a dummy delay, use the default Channel.RENDEZVOUS channel, which makes sure that the element gets processed before moving on, and doesn't add any more delay than necessary.

Comment: `Channel.RENDEZVOUS` won't work as `BroadcastChannel` won't accept a size of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments stated, using `Channel.CONFLATED` will store only the last value, and you are offering to the `channel`, even if your flow has a buffer.

Also `join()` will suspend until the `Job` is not complete, in your case infinitely, that's why you needed the timeout.

```
 val channel = Channel<Int>(Channel.RENDEZVOUS)
 val flowJob = channel.consumeAsFlow().onEach {
     println(it)
 }.launchIn(GlobalScope)

GlobalScope.launch{
    for (i in 0..100) {
        channel.send(i * i)
    }
    channel.close()
}
flowJob.join()
```

Check out this solution ([playground link](https://pl.kotl.in/nrt-e_1yU)), with the `Channel.RENDEZVOUS` your channel will accept new elements only if the others are already consumed.
This is why we have to use `send` instead of `offer`, `send` suspends until it can send elements, while `offer` returns a boolean indicating if send was succesfull.
At last, we have to `close` the channel, in order for `join()` not to suspend until eternity.